# Use data in Excel file to to create a new Excel file

Tags: excel, matlab

My objective is to calculate the mean values of data in an Excel file and store these in a new Excel file. I'm not sure if I'm using functions correctly.

- `[numD, txtD] = xlsread('filename', 'sheet','xlrange')`

  where `numD` is the numerical data, `txtD` is the string data
- `xlswrite(filename, dataA, sheet,'xlrange')`
- `~feof`
- `fprintf(fidw,'string with data %d',dataIn);`

Can I pass the variable name "data" into calculating the mean?
Would "data" need to be in curly brackets?
Would the same go for "txtData"?

`txtData` represents the string values of the Excel file that I want to use in the new file I'm making.

[This is what I'm trying to create (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRZ0F.png)

```
function [ ] = CIMISmeanAirQuality(fileNameIn,fileNameOut,sheetName,dataRange)

    [data,txtData] = xlsread('fileNameIn.xlsx','sheetName','dataRange');

    headers =(txtData);%if files have cell arrays of strings use this

    values = mean(data);% find the mean of data in columns

    xlswrite('fileNameOut.xlsx',[headers;values] ,'sheetName','A1:J2');

end
```

My error my be due to incomplete code and/or not saving the Excel file correctly. However the Excel file does appear to be in my current MATLAB folder.

```
Error using xlsread (line 128)
XLSREAD unable to open file 'fileNameIn.xlsx'.
File '/Users/kenziecampbell/Documents/MATLAB/fileNameIn.xlsx' not found.

Error in CIMISmeanAirQuality (line 18)
[data,txtData] = xlsread('fileNameIn.xlsx','sheetName','dataRange');
```

Comment: Can you please describe, what doesn't work as expected? Does it throw any errors, or is the result wrong? If so, please describe what the desired result is, and what the actual result of your code is. Thank you

Comment: There is also the csvread function which can be used for this kind of data.

Comment: Thats what Im confused about should I also be using csv functions. Can I use both xls and csv? @C.Colden

Comment: @hbaderts    Im not sure if Im not saving the excel file correctly or if my code doesn't make sense or both , above I added what my error says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the mean values that you have in the .csv file in matlab and then further work on it in a new excel spreadsheet it would be better to use uiopen.

For Example: I saved the following data as prac_read_table.csv into my excel spreadsheet.

(data 1)
5
10
12
12
12
12

(data 2)
8
8
8
8
8
8

(data 3) 
34
25
43
65
29
63

(means)15.66666667
14.33333333
21
28.33333333
16.33333333
27.66666667

Then, I went to matlab and typed `uiopen('C:\Users\Nicholas\Documents\MATLAB\prac_read_table.csv',1)`
This prompts open a window asking you what you would like to import. I select only the mean values since that is what you want.

This then saves my mean values into a variable called means since I already have that as a subtitle in excel.

To save the means into a new excel spreadsheet you would use the `xlswrite` function you already have written.

Comment: , So the readtable function would replace my first line of code?     And would finding mean just be the mean of the variable name i set readtable to?

Comment: Yes it would essentially do all of those things that you have listed in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your means in the column in the .csv file then all you would have to do is call the assigned variable name to get that list of means.

Comment: I originally have a csv excel file of data and Im trying to create a new excel document with the means.  In this case would  I have T=readtable(fileNameIn.xlsx)      and mean(T) ?

Comment: I rewrote my first answer to accommodate your needs. It wouldn't be readtable since you want to continue using the means.